# e-mail as object name

Tags: php

I have a XML with a node called 'e-mail'. I use simplexml_load_file to read the file but when i want to get the row value with $row->e-mail i get just get 0 back.

What's wrong here, all other names work fine so i think it has something to do with 'mail'.

tnx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)

> Accessing elements within an XML
>   document that contain characters not
>   permitted under PHP's naming
>   convention (e.g. the hyphen) can be
>   accomplished by encapsulating the
>   element name within braces and the
>   apostrophe.
>
> echo
>   $xml->movie->{'great-lines'}->line;

So you need something like

```
$row->{'e-mail'}
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
$row->{'e-mail'}
```

Comment: and `$row->e-mail` evaluates to 0 cuz `$row->e` is null and `mail` evaluates to literal `'mail'`, so you have `null-'mail'` which is 0.